# Node or Grunt plugin to watch files access

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

We have lot of node modules and grunt plugins to watch the files that change, add or delete but is there any way we get the list of files being accessed?

I need to create a script in node or grunt.js to list down all the files being accessed in the web folder to remove the unused files. Any other suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: this doesnt help you directly but when you run grunt in --verbose mode, it logs all the files it touches

Comment: In my case the browser / webserver is actually "touching the files" and I need to log that "Touch" :)

Comment: Just to make this idea of "I'll just do ... to prune unused files" more problematic: how would you know the difference between a file being accessed by node or grunt, or by a text editor, or even by the OS for search indexing? A better approach would be to make sure that any file that doesn't belong in the dir never lands there, and file relevancy being based on through-your-app user access (stored in an index, for instance) instead of through-the-filesystem access.

Comment: node logs the files it serves, capture that and then just remove duplicates